# Flutter debugger cannot evaluate variable

Tags: flutter, api, android-studio

So I'm importing data using private api and trying to implement some of the data into variables -

```
lastName: getJsonField((verifyEmail?.jsonBody ?? ''), r'''$.lname''',).toString();
```

lastName for example in the debugger - doesn't get a value for some reason, it Cannot evaluate it
while if i look up only the expression

```
getJsonField((verifyEmail?.jsonBody ?? ''), r'''$.lname''',).toString()
```

I'll get the value that i intend to get. Anything wrong with the way im trying to save it in vars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, flutter doesn't imply the value of the jsonField into the new variable, happens specifically when trying to push variables to other pages

Solution:

```
lastName: AuthCandCall.authLname(api?.jsonBody ?? '').toString();
```

AuthCandCall - the api response endpoint's name

authLname - specifically one of the parameter from the api's response